# Move to the last character of previous line vim

Tags: vim

I have started using vim recently and was wondering if there's any keyboard shortcut to move the the last character of previous line( line number l-1 if I am currently on line number l) ?

One of the ways is to use the up arrow to move to the same column of previous line and then use $ to move to the end of the line.
I am looking for some shortcut to do that in one command.

Comment: Why not press 0 and Backspace? They are near to each other and no need for another mapping.

Comment: 0 and backspace don't work. 0 does take me to the start of the line, but backspace doesn't move to the last character of previous line.

Comment: I heard about problems with backspace on earlier versions of  vim and some terminals. What OS, vim version, terminal do you use?

Comment: I am using macOS and vim version 8.0

Comment: What shows `:set whichwrap?` command?

Comment: It gives the following : whichwrap=b,s

Comment: Hm, that's strange. I have same settings on Ubuntu and Windows with vim 8.x and backspace moves cursor to line above. Sorry, have no more idea why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Here's also another solution to move to the beginning of the next line / the end of the previous line without the need to set any mappings. Add these three to your .vimrc:

```
set whichwrap+=<,h
set whichwrap+=>,l
set whichwrap+=[,]
```

(Credit to: [Kevin H. Lin and garyjohn](https://superuser.com/a/431239/945105))

---

**Original Answer:**

I've not memorized all Vim shortcut combinations, so *there might be one* shortcut for what you're asking for, but I usually define a mapping whenever I need something I don't know how to do.

For what you need, you can simply define it with this:

```
nnoremap <S-L> <Up><S-4>
```

Just add it to your `~/.vimrc`(if this file doesn't exist yet, create it yourself), then restart vim. Then the next time you open up your Vim, the "Shift-L" shortcut will do the job.

You can go straight into the insert mode as well and append characters after the last character of the previous line with this rule instead:

```
nnoremap <S-L> <Up><S-A>
```

Also in case you don't understand the structure of the above rules, you can read more about it here:
[Understand Vim Mappings and Create Your Own Shortcuts](https://medium.com/vim-drops/understand-vim-mappings-and-create-your-own-shortcuts-f52ee4a6b8ed).

Answer (score 1):

There is a corner case: If your cursor is on the first line, pressing this mapping should not move the cursor.
Therefore, we can use the `<expr>` mapping:

```
nnoremap <expr> <F6> line('.')==1?'\<F6>':'k$'
```

In the example above, I used `<F6>`, you can choose the short-cut key you like.